# enabling CORS in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, cors, http-status-code-404

Im Trying to parse a link using XmlRequest but Im getting 404 error , nothing is wrong with the link it's working fine, 
After Googling i thaught that the problem might be with my confguration i dunno how to enable CORS and add it to my applicationhost.config
any help would be apperciated .
 here's my code :

**Index.HTML:**

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Ticket</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
   <script src="script.js"></script>
   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
   </head>
   <body>
   <button onclick="Next();">Next</button>
   <footer id="currentTicket">loading...</footer>
   </body>
```

**Script.JS**

```
var currentTicketId = 0;
var lastTicket;

function GetCurrentTicketId() {
var request = HttpRequest("http://localhost:6164/api/tickets?IsDone=false",  
"GET", "");
request.onreadystatechange = function () {
if (request.readyState == 4) {
if (request.status == 200) {
var Ticket = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
lastTicket = Ticket;
currentTicketId = Ticket.id;
document.getElementById("currentTicket").innerHTML = "current  
ticket is " + Ticket.ticketNumber;

}
else {
document.getElementById("currentTicket").innerHTML = "Error";
}
}
}
}

function HttpRequest(Url, Method, Parameter) {
var httpClient = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpClient.open(Method, Url, true);
httpClient.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-    
urlencoded");
httpClient.send(Parameter);
return httpClient;
}

function Next() {
var request = HttpRequest("http://localhost:6164/api/tickets" +     
currentTicketId, "PUT", lastTicket);
request.onreadystatechange = function () {
if (request.readyState == 4) {
if (request.status == 200) {
var Ticket = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
lastTicket = Ticket;
currentTicketId++;
document.getElementById("currentTicket").innerHTML = "current  
 ticket is " + Ticket.ticketNumber;
 } else {
document.getElementById("currentTicket").innerHTML = "no more 

taken tickets";
}
}
}
}

GetCurrentTicketId();
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just reboot your computer and it will work :D

Comment: Not every problem get solved by rebooting the computer :(